# How do I update a mongodb array

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How can I update update list of picture?

Model:

```
public class Test
    {
        [BsonId]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Picture> Pic {get; set; }
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    }

    public class Picture
    {
        public string Name{ get; set;}
        public int Size {get; set;}
    }
```

Update code:

```
 IMongoUpdate update = Update
                .Set("Name", test.Name)
                .Set("Address", test.Address)
                .Set("LastModified", test.LastModified);
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id": "50d3dbce1292dd2e98af1dd1",
    "Name": "Bubba",
    "Address": "1111",
    "Pic" : [{"Name": "test1.jpg", "Size":"1000"}, {"Name": "test2.jpg", "Size":"2000"}],
    "LastModified": {
        "$date": "2012-12-21T03:47:26.535Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps the manual could be of assistance. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-Updatemethod

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update entire collection you could use this code

```
var update = Update<Test>.Set(x => x.Pic, new List<Picture> {new Picture {Name="name", Size=10}});
collection.Update(Query<Test>.EQ(x => x.Id, "1"), update);
```

There are methods to modify collection in Update class: AddToSet, Push, Pull, Pop...

If you need to update all fields of document then it's easier to update whole document

```
collection.Update(document)
```

In this case BsonId field must be setted.